# Creating executable for user input

Tags: java, cmd, exe, executable

I have a java program that takes in user input via `Console.readLine()`, and I want to create an **exe** file for easy use. However, when I do this there is no console prompt for user input. How would I create an executable that allows this, or alternatively how would I adjust my program so that it can be run as an **exe** allowing user input?

Comment: This is kind of surprising to me.  Shouldn't `Console.readLine()` pause the console until someone enters information?  I think you should look into using a `Scanner`.

Comment: It does pause the console if I run the Class file through the console. But with the exe I generated, the console doesn't even open up

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion would be to create a simple Swing GUI and then create a jar file out of your class files. If set up correctly, double clicking on the jar file will display the GUI and allow you to get user input, even if run in many different operating systems.